# How to prevent router identification

Tags: network, privacy, isp

How to prevent my router (D-Link AC1200 LTE Router DW-953) which is using a 4G sim card for data from being identified by an ISP?

The router has the current Firmware Version V01.02.3.045, with no VPN or L2TP setup option.

I'd like to know how to prevent the ISP from identifying my device.

Comment: The question is not fully clear to me. But it sounds  like your ISP is having a policy of only allowing specific devices on their network or to make sure that a SIM is bound to a specific device - and that you try to bypass this policy for your own gain. This kind of question is off-topic here.

Comment: Are you basically facing the same problem that people use "unlocked" cell phones for?

Comment: @forest Hi, my router use a sim card to access data, my ISP is currently able to identify the device information

Comment: @forest: The OP clearly said in a previous edit that the ISP is blocking the access if he uses a different router which in my opinion suggests that the OP wants to bypass an explicit policy. The OP now removed this part from the question which makes it open to interpretation why the OP wants to do this. This in essence makes an an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), i.e. the OP explains what he wants to do but no longer the underlying problem - probably knowing that if the underlying problem is explained that the question gets closed. Based on this I stay to my vote.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ah, I didn't check the edits. I still think it's on-topic even if he wants to do that, but I also think that it could be closed as _unclear_.

Comment: @Jones: *"I'd like to know how to prevent the router from being identified by ISP since they can detect device information"* -  You effectively say with this that you want to prevent Y since ISP can do Y. You don't say why Y is a problem for you in the current edit of your question. But you said it in your initial form of the question: the ISP will block you if you use a a specific device. Thus, you want to **bypass restrictions for your own gain** which like I've already said is off-topic here.

Comment: @forest I agree with Steffen. Bypassing controls can be a fine question. But, wanting to bypass vendor controls as a customer for personal benefit falls on the wrong side of the line.